# How do I programmatically check if the menu of my activity is showing at a particular moment?

Tags: android, menu

An Android device configuration change (for example "slide the hard keyboard back in") will always call `PhoneWindow.onConfigurationChanged()`, which in turn, will call `reopenMenu()`. This will cause the menu of the currently running activity to be reopened, in case it is showing.

I have a lock on my menu implemented in my `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` override. The user must enter a code each time they want to see the menu. I don't want the user to be asked to enter the code again, while the menu is still up just because of a configuration change. Thus, I would like to know, is there any way I can check if the menu of current foreground activity is already showing? Knowing this, I could bypass asking for the access code if the menu is already up.

My custom workaround implementation is to use my own flag `menuShowing`, which I set in `onPrepareOptionsMenu` and reset in `onOptionsItemSelected` and in `onKeyDown` if the back button is clicked.

`EDIT:` It appears a screen orientation configuration change does not trigger this behavior. A hard keyboard slide however, does.

Comment: After my various efforts, I think your custom boolean approach is best. You might be able to simplify it with `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`: true and `onOptionsMenuClosed()`: false (since this will be called by either selecting an item or pressing a hard key: back, home, menu). FYI, you can support one type hard keyboard slide in the emulator by setting the hardware properties to not having a hard keyboard in portrait and having one in landscape, should that be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Until someone comes up with a nicer 'one call' answer, here is the custom workaround implementation that I mention in the question, with help from Sam's tips, in case someone needs the same functionality:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (showingMenu) {
        // The menu button was clicked or the hard keyboard was
        // slid open/closed while the menu was already showing
        return true;
    }
    // Otherwise, either the menu was clicked or openOptionsMenu() was called
    if (codeEntered) {
        // Code was entered and then openOptionsMenu() was called
        showingMenu = true;
        // Menu will now be shown
        return true;
    } else {
        // The menu button was clicked, ask for code
        askForCode();
        // Don't show menu yet
        return false;
    }
}    

@Override
public void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu) {
    showingMenu = false;
    codeEntered = false;
}

private void askForCode() {
    codeEntered = getUserInput();
    if (codeEntered)
        openOptionsMenu();
}
```

`getUserInput()` actually occurs with the help of an `AlertDialog` and an `EditText` with an attached `TextWatcher` but the implementation details exceed the scope of this question, unless someone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it´s

```
  @Override
  public void onPanelClosed(int featureId, Menu menu) {
    showingMenu = false;
    super.onPanelClosed(featureId, menu);
}
```