# How to check that options menu is opened?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

How to check that options menu is opened? (menu in actionbar, or menu from preference button in older devices) There is some method for this?

Comment: You want to check if option me is **opened** or if option menu is **clicked** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this SO question :

[How do I programmatically check if the menu of my activity is showing at a particular moment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10542973/how-do-i-programmatically-check-if-the-menu-of-my-activity-is-showing-at-a-parti)

Not a proper solution but the best workaround possible at the moment.