# Android popup menu opened listener

Tags: android

For the [Popup Menu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html) there is a `PopupMenu.OnDismissListener` and a `PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener` but no `OnOpenedListener`. Is there a way to determine when a popup menu is opened?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990197/how-to-check-that-options-menu-is-opened

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check that options menu is opened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20990197/how-to-check-that-options-menu-is-opened)

Comment: Both of them explicitly state that it is not a proper solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popup Menu needs to be anchored to a View so I just had to add a click listener to the view and I could determine when the popup menu was opened.